# Dotted line between List Items in JqueryMobile ListView

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile listview and it's working fine. In jquery list between list items i'm able to see some space which looks as a seperator. I want to seperate them with dotted line between list items instead of that space. How can i acheive this? can anyone please help me. i hope my question is clear.

Something like this:

```
List1
...........................
List2
...........................
List3
...........................
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
        .dotted-list li{
            border-style:dotted;
            border-color:#000;
        }
        .dotted-list li:first-of-type{
            border-style:solid ;
            border-color:#ff0000;
        }

        .dotted-list li:last-of-type{
            border-bottom-style:solid ;
            border-bottom-color:#ff0000;
        }
```

List is defined as:

```
      <ul data-role="listview" class="dotted-list">
        <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test5</a></li>
      </ul>
```

A demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/wYSqk/

Comment: Thnaks for ur reply.It helped me alot.